# Fancytree change drag and drop icons

Tags: icons, fancytree

How can I change the drag and drop icons in the .gif file (skin-win8/icons.gif).  Also, what is the difference between icons.gif and icons-rtl.gif?  I don't understand how it works (having multiple icons the the same gif).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These are three questions in one:

> I don't understand how it works (having multiple icons the the same gif).

Multiple images are combined into one and are selectively displayed by different background offsets ('[image sprites](http://I%20don't%20understand%20how%20it%20works%20(having%20multiple%20icons%20the%20the%20same%20gif).)')

> what is the difference between icons.gif and icons-rtl.gif?

the rtl variant is used if the right-to-left direction option is on (`rtl: true`)

> How can I change the drag and drop icons in the .gif

With an image editor, of course. But it would be easier to add additional, custom css rules that override the background image and offset. Refer to the [theming tutorial](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialTheming) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!  It helped me!

Comment: You're welcome :) If the answer was helpful, consider 'accepting' it...